# how to use deferred with https.request in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest, deferred

I use github to authenticate in my node application. I have constructed the following code:

```
var req = request(postOptions, function (res) {
  res.on('data', function (d) {
    ...
    var getOptions = parseUrl('https://api.github.com/user?access_token=' + accessToken);
    ...
    var req = request(getOptions, function (resp) {
      ...
      resp.on('data', function (d) {
        ...
      })
        .on('end', function () {
           ...
        })
    });

    req.end();
  });
});

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

I've removed some code, because the point here is that I have a request in a request. Now, nodejs has [deferreds](https://www.npmjs.org/package/deferred) The question is if this can be used to simplify the above code ?

Comment: Check out `promisify`. But generally speaking, code must support promises for promises to work.

Comment: what is the problem with this code?

Comment: @mihai Events offer more granularity than promises/deferreds. Promise can be either fulfilled or rejected and only once, their state with respect to task at hand is running or finished. There is no equivalent of event 'data' in promise. Events give you ability to step through the task, promises only tell you of running and exit code. It may be possible to replace it with promise. But they lack the expressivness.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have no error handling. Promises significantly cleans up code that correctly propagates errors and doesn't leak resources because those become automatic. So it's impossible to make a fair comparison because promise code that doesn't handle errors still propagates them.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require("request"));

function githubAuthenticate() {
  return request.postAsync(postOptions, postData)
    .spread(function(response, body) {
      var accessToken = ...
      var getOptions = parseUrl('https://api.github.com/user?access_token=' + accessToken);
      return request.getAsync(getOptions);
    })
    .spread(function(response, body) {

    });
}
```

Now imagine if something failed here? You would add a `.catch` only once, in one place, and handle it there. Since errors automatically propagate, the code above doesn't need to do anything. The consumer code can just do:

```
  gitHubAuthenticate().then(function() {

  }).catch(function(err) {
      // Any error that happened with the post, get or your code gets here
      // automatically
  });
```

Comment: Mmm, confusing use of "client" there, methinks.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 how so? :P

Comment: "Client" implies the client side of client-server. Given that we're talking about node.js here, all this presumably runs server-side. If I'm right, then I would avoid ambiguity by saying "the consumer code ...".

Comment: @Roamer-1888 yes by client code I mean the calling code, or the consumer of the api as you say,